# The cultists are missing in the 'Boethiah's Calling' quest

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

At level 29, I came to the shrine of Boethiah and put my follower on the conduit but I hadn't started the quest. I am now level 30 and have started the quest. I sacrificed the follower and it says I must kill all of the cultists yet there are none to kill

I am trying to get the Ebony Mail and I want to know how I can fix it.

Comment: Is there no one around at all? What about the person that gave you the quest?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not completely sure but I think I read somewhere that sometimes they aren't there. Try waiting there or in a different cell for a while (from a few hours to a few days) and then head back. They might be there then. If you have PC you could use console commands to technically start the quest. Other than that I'm not sure.